# Where can I find a correlation to Russell's epistemology in the Tractatus?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, wittgenstein, bertrand-russell

According to the Structure of the Tractatus, there is:

1) the *ontology* at the beginning;

2) "a discussion to what Russell calls *epistemology*, but it is actually the foundation of possible *knowledge* by a scientific model / by an objective thought".

3) And in the second part (sections 2, 3...) he made an *analysis of language*...

4)... and found that this structure has finally *ethics* (the Mystic).

---

- Which commentaries are related to 2) "what Russell calls epistemology"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following [Russell's Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=2yYPeIjgeAcC&pg=PR9), I'm not sure that we can find a *Theory of Knowledge* in the *Tractatus*... According to your indications, it must be section 2.0.

Having said that, possible references to [Russell's philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell/#RWAP) are:

- Bertrand Russell, [Theory of Knowledge: The 1913 Manuscript](https://books.google.it/books?id=gSxwOHzNXlQC&printsec=frontcover) (1st ed., 1984)
- Bertrand Russell, [The Philosophy of Logical Atomism](https://books.google.it/books?id=sdOLAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1918); see also [Russell's Logical Atomism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-atomism/) and [Wittgenstein's Logical Atomism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-atomism/).